# How to Minify JSX files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, requirejs

I'm working with React.Net + requireJs, my questions are:

1.how can I minify my jsx files

2.how can I minify my jsx files in a way that i won't harm the current code, i.e.: some of my requireJs injections are like this:

```
require(['!jsx/someJsxFilePath'])
```

Will I have to change this after I minify, if yes, how?

Comment: Are you loading each component as an individual `.jsx` file from the server to the client (one network request per file)?

Comment: Yes, managed by requireJS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compiled/minified jsx file is bigger than original file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001565/compiled-minified-jsx-file-is-bigger-than-original-file)